# Wireless problem Dell Inspiron 5520 with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 5520 laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. My wireless connection has problems. It would work for a while and then stop working without any reason. That means that Firefox stop loading pages, Skype disconnects, drop box disconnects. But the Wireless Network is still connected and I have very good signal. The only way to reactivate internet is plug in the lan cable or restart the laptop. I Googled a bit and find that other people had problems with this laptop wireless connection on Ubuntu, like the machine not detecting the wireless connection but this is a different issue. 
Here is the output of `lspci -vv`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 44
    Region 0: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 41
    Region 0: Memory at c0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 45
    Region 0: Memory at c0614000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei
    Kernel modules: mei

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at c0619000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 46
    Region 0: Memory at c0610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0400000-00000000c04fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: c0500000-c05fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
    Region 0: Memory at c0618000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 40
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3088 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at 3094 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 3080 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 3090 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 3060 [size=32]
    Region 5: Memory at c0617000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 10
    Region 0: Memory at c0615000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 3040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0569
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 42
    Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at c0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at c0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 43
    Region 0: Memory at c0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: wl, iwlwifi
```

Thanks in advance for the help

@chili555 Here is the last part of the output of dmesg | grep -e wlan -e iwl after the wifi connection got stucked

```
[ 6843.533827] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00880302
[ 6843.533833] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X0000ff40
[ 6843.533839] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X80000000
[ 6843.533845] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[ 6843.533852] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00010000
[ 6843.533858] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[ 6843.533864] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000000
[ 6843.533870] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080403c5
[ 6843.533876] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X000000c8
[ 6843.533882] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0Xfccf0ffd
[ 6843.533888] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X90000801
[ 6843.533894] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X00030001
[ 6843.533900] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X00080044
[ 6843.533906] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X0000a274
[ 6843.533913] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000080
[ 6843.533918] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[ 6843.533924] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[ 6843.533930] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000078
[ 6843.533937] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X8822d721
[ 6843.533942] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X29800200
[ 6843.533948] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0X00000000
[ 6843.533955] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[ 6843.533961] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0000
[ 6843.533964] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH register values:
[ 6843.533980] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X22cf2a00
[ 6843.533995] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X022c4440
[ 6843.534011] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X000000e8
[ 6843.534026] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X80819104
[ 6843.534041] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X000000fc
[ 6843.534057] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X07030000
[ 6843.534072] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
[ 6843.534087] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X07ff0001
[ 6843.534103] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[ 6843.534160] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 20 entries
[ 6843.534181] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856206:0x000000ad:1600
[ 6843.534193] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856207:0x00000000:1629
[ 6843.534206] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856207:0x00000008:0220
[ 6843.534218] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856225:0x00000000:0302
[ 6843.534230] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856253:0x00002000:1243
[ 6843.534242] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856256:0x000000d4:0303
[ 6843.534255] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856260:0x0000187b:0217
[ 6843.534267] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856260:0x0b7a001c:0217
[ 6843.534280] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856263:0x00040000:1243
[ 6843.534293] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856333:0x00000000:0708
[ 6843.534305] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856335:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6843.534317] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856349:0x00000000:0708
[ 6843.534330] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856351:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6843.534342] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856358:0x00000000:0708
[ 6843.534354] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856360:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6843.534367] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856367:0x00000000:0708
[ 6843.534379] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856369:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6843.534391] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856376:0x00000000:0708
[ 6843.534404] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856378:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6843.534416] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0192856395:0x00000000:0125
[ 6843.534767] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[ 6843.542130] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[ 6916.660708] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Tx aggregation enabled on ra = ee:9f:ef:35:46:dc tid = 0
[ 6916.711445] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[ 6916.711455] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 18.168.6.1
[ 6916.711541] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 6916.711547] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x000412E4, count: 6
[ 6916.711554] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000EDC | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[ 6916.711559] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00026B94 | uPc
[ 6916.711564] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00026B1C | branchlink1
[ 6916.711568] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00026B1C | branchlink2
[ 6916.711573] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000EC7A | interruptlink1
[ 6916.711578] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[ 6916.711583] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xF0F45CE8 | data1
[ 6916.711588] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB83C1050 | data2
[ 6916.711592] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000AF4 | line
[ 6916.711596] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB2C1568A | beacon time
[ 6916.711601] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xD3894976 | tsf low
[ 6916.711606] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | tsf hi
[ 6916.711610] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 6916.711615] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x045DCE16 | time gp2
[ 6916.711619] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp3
[ 6916.711624] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x754312A8 | uCode version
[ 6916.711628] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000000C8 | hw version
[ 6916.711633] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00880302 | board version
[ 6916.711637] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xB83C1050 | hcmd
[ 6916.711642] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CSR values:
[ 6916.711646] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[ 6916.711656] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00880302
[ 6916.711665] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X00000040
[ 6916.711673] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X80000000
[ 6916.711681] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[ 6916.711690] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00010000
[ 6916.711698] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[ 6916.711707] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000000
[ 6916.711716] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080403c5
[ 6916.711723] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X000000c8
[ 6916.711731] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0Xfccf0ffd
[ 6916.711739] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X90000801
[ 6916.711748] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X00030001
[ 6916.711755] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X00080044
[ 6916.711763] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00004ac4
[ 6916.711771] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000080
[ 6916.711779] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[ 6916.711787] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[ 6916.711794] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000078
[ 6916.711803] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X8822d721
[ 6916.711811] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X29800200
[ 6916.711819] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0X00000000
[ 6916.711827] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[ 6916.711836] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0000
[ 6916.711840] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH register values:
[ 6916.711858] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X22cf2a00
[ 6916.711877] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X022c4440
[ 6916.711895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X00000078
[ 6916.711913] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X80819104
[ 6916.711931] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X000000fc
[ 6916.711949] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X07030000
[ 6916.711968] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
[ 6916.711987] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X07ff0001
[ 6916.712005] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[ 6916.712066] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 20 entries
[ 6916.712090] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256384:0x00001aa0:0217
[ 6916.712105] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256385:0x0b9f001c:0217
[ 6916.712120] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256387:0x00040000:1243
[ 6916.712136] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256396:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712151] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256397:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712166] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256404:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712181] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256406:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712195] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256413:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712210] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256415:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712225] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256422:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712240] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256424:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712255] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256431:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712269] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256433:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712284] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256440:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712298] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256442:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712313] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256449:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712328] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256451:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712343] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256458:0x00000000:0708
[ 6916.712358] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256460:0x000000d9:0736
[ 6916.712373] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0073256477:0x00000000:0125
[ 6916.712880] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[ 6916.720295] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
```

Comment: I notice it says that the module wl is installed.That is for Broadcom products, not Intel. Please do: sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source; sudo modprobe -r wl. Any improvement?

Comment: I tried that, but I got no improvement...

Comment: Are there any clues in the message logs? dmesg | grep -e wlan -e iwl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me, here is the link:

http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/

The second method stated in the link is the one I tried, and worked well in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:  `sudo rfkill unblock all`

Comment: Tried that, nothing has changed..